# Heat dissipated on switching the wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]

$C$ and $C_0$ are the capacitance of the capacitors. The wire marked with an arrowhead is to be switched from point 1 to 2. Resistance of wires is very very less (~0). Leaking of charge does not occur. Total capacitance of system in the two cases remains same hence no change in energy of conductors. This made me conclude that no EXTRA work is being done by the battery(which is obviously incorrect). Why is the battery doing extra work and what will be its expression?

Comment: How is heat dissipated if you're ignoring resistance?

Comment: This question is not possible to answer ignoring resistance.

Comment: I've edited the question. The resistance of wires tends to 0 but is not exactly 0.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitance of the wires in a DC circuit?  Assuming real capacitors so that the top of your circuit is isolated from the bottom, then the total charge on the top is zero and does not change.  Using q = CV, it can be shown (with some effort) that the initial charge on the right side capacitor is equal to the final charge on the left side capacitor.  Thus the battery delivers no net charge to the circuit. (Co reverses polarity.)

Comment: But when switching from position 1 to position 2 will there not be a redistribution of  the charge on the outer two capacitors?

Comment: Yes, the charge on the left side capacitor goes from (C/Co)CV  to  (1+C/Co)CV, but it has gone from having Co in parallel to not having Co in parallel. Charge flows from the battery when the switch is opened, but goes back again when it is closed. With no resistance, there is  no heat generated.

Answer (score 0):

What does "$C$ and $C_o$ are the capacitance of the wires" mean, anyway? There can be capacitance between wires and between wires and say ground, but wires themselves don't have "capacitance".

I'm going to assume the circuit is simply a combination of capacitors in series and parallel and the wires having zero resistance at face value. Given that, there are two separate issues here.

First there's the title of your post. If there is no resistance in the circuit, then there can be no heat dissipated. If there is resistance, and there is always some, then heat will be dissipated if charge moves around as a result of switching from position 1 to position 2.

Second is the question of whether or not the battery has to do any "work" in connection with switching from position 1 to position 2. We know that when switching from position 1 to 2 there will be a redistribution of  charge on the outer two capacitors. That’s because they change from being in parallel with $C_o$ to being in series with $C_o$.  However, since the total stored energy on all the capacitors does not change in going from position 1 to position 2, theoretically no work is done in connection with the redistribution of charge.

I say theoretically because in reality there will always be some resistance in the wires and capacitors that has to be overcome if charge is redistributed, which means that the redistribution of charge (which equates to current) will have result in heat dissipation. That means the battery will have to do "extra work" to redistribute the charge.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we take resistance to be very low, can we derive a mathematical expression for the heat dissipated?

Comment: Yes, but now you have a different problem than your original question that R.W. Bird and I answered. You can't keep changing the parameters of the question. Ask a new question and show the locations of the resistance in the circuit.